# событие когда бота добавили на сервер а он написал сообщение

Tags: javascript, discord

Как сделать событие когда при добавлений бота на сервер он что то написал в канал?

Например добавили ME6 на сервер и он написал сообщение: *"Привет! Я рад что добавил меня на сервер"*

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример:

```
//joined a server
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log("Joined a new guild: " + guild.name);
    //Your other stuff like adding to guildArray
})

//removed from a server
client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    console.log("Left a guild: " + guild.name);
    //remove from guildArray
})
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523105/what-event-is-fired-when-a-discord-bot-joins-a-guild)

Comment: так не discord py а discord js

Comment: изменил ответ..